# UICollectionView contentSize not update height

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I use this custom UICollectionView to make my collection view height base on contentSize

```
public class SelfSizingCollectionView: UICollectionView {
  public override init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
    super.init(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    commonInit()
  }
  
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
  }
  
  private func commonInit() {
    isScrollEnabled = false
  }
  
  public override var contentSize: CGSize {
    didSet {
      invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
  }
  
  public override func reloadData() {
    super.reloadData()
    self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
  }
  
  public override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return contentSize
  }
}
```

but the problem is when the number of cell data decreases, the collection view height does not decrease too

sorry for my bad englis, but you can see this video for better understanding about my problems
[Problem Record](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b5VwJmH_Bj--8fWAzkChzogABMknG6mD/view?usp=sharing)

The collection view height should update the height